# SQL Server Identity column does not behave properly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a table named `tblEmployees` with code -

```
Create table tblEmployees
(
    EmployeeID int identity primary key,
    Name nvarchar(30),
    Salary float,
    Gender tinyint
)
```

Then I inserted values-

```
insert into tblEmployees values ('Akmal', 5000, 0)
insert into tblEmployees values ('Shakira', 6000, 1)
insert into tblEmployees values ('Kiron', 7000, 2)
insert into tblEmployees values ('Jamil', 5500, 0)
insert into tblEmployees values ('Faul', 4800, 4)
```

But, when the values are shown -

```
EmployeeID  Name      Salary    Gender
2           Akmal     5000          0
3           Shakira   6000          1
4           Kiron     7000          2
5           Jamil     5500          0
7           Faul      4800          4
```

My question is, why EmployeeID column started with 2? And where is 6? Shouldnt this be incremented automatically?

Comment: `IDENTITY(1,1)` would have started the identity column at 1 with increments of 1.

Comment: The problem is in assuming that it matters if EmployeeID has gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your T-SQL script is incomplete because my IDENTITY values are generated starting with 1 (and ending with 5).

Note #0: I'm only try to describe some reasons for those missing IDENTITY values.

Note #1: Don't run this script on a production server.

Note #2: Using `IDENTITY` within a column definition means `IDENTITY(1,1)` <=> `IDENTITY(seed value/initial value=1,increment value=1)`.

Note #3: You should avoid using `DBCC CHECKIDENT` if you aren't aware about the [consequences of this command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx).

**The first missing value (a possible explanation):**

> why EmployeeID column started with 2?

Run the following script:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.tblEmployees') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.tblEmployees;
GO
Create table tblEmployees
(
    EmployeeID int identity primary key,
    Name nvarchar(30),
    Salary float,
    Gender tinyint
)
GO
insert into tblEmployees values ('Akmal', 5000, 0)
insert into tblEmployees values ('Shakira', 6000, 1)
insert into tblEmployees values ('Kiron', 7000, 2)
insert into tblEmployees values ('Jamil', 5500, 0)
insert into tblEmployees values ('Faul', 4800, 4)
GO
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [Last IDENTITY  #1];
/*
Last IDENTITY #1
----------------
5
*/
GO
```

At this moment the last IDENTITY value generated for this table is (as you can see) 5 and not 7 (like your example).

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tblEmployees;
/*
EmployeeID  Name                           Salary                 G
----------- ------------------------------ ---------------------- -
1           Akmal                          5000                   0
2           Shakira                        6000                   1
3           Kiron                          7000                   2
4           Jamil                          5500                   0
5           Faul                           4800                   4
*/
GO
```

All rows have continuous IDENTITY values: there are no gaps.

Now, for some reasons, somebody deletes all rows from `dbo.tblEmployees` and also decides to *reset* (RESEED) the last identity value (which is 5) to 1 (from 5 to 1).

```
DELETE dbo.tblEmployees;
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.tblEmployees', RESEED, 1);
GO
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [Last IDENTITY  #2];
/*
Last IDENTITY #2
----------------
1
*/
GO
```

Now, the last IDENTITY value is 1 (because of that RESEED 1).

```
insert into tblEmployees values ('Akmal', 5000, 0)
insert into tblEmployees values ('Shakira', 6000, 1)
insert into tblEmployees values ('Kiron', 7000, 2)
insert into tblEmployees values ('Jamil', 5500, 0)
insert into tblEmployees values ('Faul', 4800, 4)
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.tblEmployees;
GO
/*
EmployeeID  Name                           Salary                 Gender
----------- ------------------------------ ---------------------- ------
2           Akmal                          5000                   0
3           Shakira                        6000                   1
4           Kiron                          7000                   2
5           Jamil                          5500                   0
6           Faul                           4800                   4
*/
```

When I insert those rows again, the first generated IDENTITY value is 2 (this time).

Why ? The reason is described in [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx):

"If no rows have been inserted into the table since the table was created, or **if all rows have been removed** by using the 
TRUNCATE TABLE statement, the first row inserted after you run DBCC CHECKIDENT uses new_reseed_value as the identity. 
**Otherwise, the next row inserted uses new_reseed_value + the current increment value.**"

This last formula explains why this time the first IDENTITY value is 2:

**new_reseed_value** (is 1 - because of RESEED 1) **+ the current increment value** (1 - see Note #2) **= 1 + 1 = 2**.

Note #4: If you are using `TRUNCATE TABLE` instead of `DELETE` then the first row inserted after `TRUNCATE TABLE` will have the ID = seed value (see Note #2) or new_reseed_value = 1. So, in this case you don't need `DBCC(..., RESEED, 1)`.

**The second missing value (a possible explanation):**

> And where is 6?

```
DELETE dbo.tblEmployees WHERE EmployeeID = 6
insert into tblEmployees values ('Faul', 4800, 4)
GO
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [Last IDENTITY  #3];
/*
Last IDENTITY #3
----------------
7
*/
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.tblEmployees;
GO
/*
EmployeeID  Name                           Salary                 Gender
----------- ------------------------------ ---------------------- ------
2           Akmal                          5000                   0
3           Shakira                        6000                   1
4           Kiron                          7000                   2
5           Jamil                          5500                   0
7           Faul                           4800                   4
*/
```

Answer (score 15):

Do not rely on `IDENTITY` columns to produce a contiguous set of values with no gaps. Period. This is not guaranteed at all; several things can cause gaps such as rollbacks, deletes, reseeds, etc. I don't believe you reproduced this problem with that exact code above; there was probably other activity in between those `INSERT` statements.

For such surrogate and meaningless values you really shouldn't care if there are gaps or not. If you care about gaps, use a different technique (e.g. a serializable max()+1 solution) - just be aware that you trade gaps for scalability / concurrency concerns. The other answer (which you accepted, but I suspect will get deleted) said:

> If you want to have an identity column with dependable and specified values then you need to set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON on that column, insert your values (with specific ID values) and then set IDENTITY_INSERT to OFF.

This only works if you already know the values you want to insert into that column. Which defeats the purpose of the `IDENTITY` property in the first place. If you don't already know what values to insert (e.g. what is the "next" `ID`), it means you need to `SELECT MAX()` from the table, and add 1 to it. Which means the whole thing needs to be serializable, otherwise someone else can read your same `MAX()` value and add the same `+1` to it. So aside from making the `IDENTITY` property useless if you're always going to override the generated value anyway, it also kills scalability by effectively limiting concurrency to 1. I highly recommend you strongly weigh that approach before implementing it.

What I suggest you do instead, is use an `IDENTITY` column, and don't be hung up on gaps. They're going to happen, there's not much you can do about it, and it shouldn't really be a concern anyway. Who cares if there is no employee #6?

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: Now isn't that interesting, because I had a database skip 1000 id's on a my shared hosted SQL Server. At least I know somebody else has seen oddities with it.

Comment: @Michael that one's a little bit different; see [this bug on Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity). It has to do with how the caching mechanism for identity values changed with the introduction of SEQUENCE in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, well at least I can explain it now! Thanks a lot friend.

Comment: @user2989408 huh? If it's a foreign key, you can't delete the parent while the child exists. But anyway, what at all did I say about reusing any values?

Comment: @user2989408 Very simplified, identity values are handed out to transactions as quickly as possible.  If a transaction rolls back (or another starts while one is processing), the mechanism that hands out identity values just keeps going up.  It doesn't rollback with the transaction, it just keeps moving along so that there is no performance impact.  For more reference, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)

Comment: @tommy_o My mistake, I meant the case where the identity col is referenced in other tables, but a Foreign Key constraint is not set up (or when cascading deletes are disabled). I know how Identity values work, and think that it is intuitive why the values keep increasing and are not reused after a rollback or delete. Thanks for the explanation though.

Answer (score -4):

Not sure why my previous answer was voted down and deleted or blocked, but if you want to have an identity column with dependable and specified values then you need to set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON on that column, insert your values (with specific ID values) and then set IDENTITY_INSERT back to OFF.

If you do not care what the values end up being (which is probably the case with an Employees table), then forget about it and learn to live with whatever these values end up being.

Comment: Please see my answer for why this suggestion to fiddle with `IDENTITY_INSERT` makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Real life situation: I had to import data for a lookup table from a previous implementation. For backward compatibility, I had to respect the IDs from the previous implementation, and after that all new lookup values would get auto generated values.

In this case, the solution was to wrote post-deploy scripts with IDENTITY_INSERT set to OFF then ON.

Sorry, unlike you I am not talking theory, I am talking real life situation.

Comment: You wrote: "Also, to do this, you need to know what value to insert. Which means you need to SELECT MAX() from the table. Which the whole thing needs to be serializable, otherwise someone else can read your same MAX() value and add the same +1 to it" Dude, read what I wrote: INSERT YOUR VALUES WITH SPECIFIC ID VALUES.

Do you read requirements before coding?

Comment: Dude, if he knows the ID values, why does he have an IDENTITY column?

Comment: Because sometimes you need to use a set of strictly specified values and then reset it as an IDENTITY so that the new IDs are populated incrementally, to let the table live its own life. This is the exact reason why you can set IDENTITY_INSERT to OFF and ON.

Comment: *sigh* /unsubscribe. Please.